# Printk or I/O dangers in interrupt handler

Tags: linux, exception, linux-kernel, printk

Why is printk or (I/O) prohibited in interrupt handler in linux .? Under what condition  I/O in a interrupt handler can  cause deadlock in a linux system?

Answer (score 1):

*Regarding `printk()`*, it is intrusive. For instance, problem you're debugging may disappear by adding printk's. Depending on settings, it may output to console which can be slow. `trace_printk()` of [ftrace](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/trace/ftrace.txt) is recommended instead.

As for *I/O inside an interrupt*, remember that interrupts run at higher priority than other threads of execution, so any latency - whether I/O or something else - will have a knock on effect on rest of the system.

*Deadlocks* can happen due to resource contention. For example, an interrupt arrives at a time when one resource, say a mutex, is already taken by a kernel thread running in process context. Now an attempt by interrupt service routine wants to acquire the same resource will result in deadlock: kernel thread can't run because ISR has higher priority and ISR can't finish because it's waiting on the resource held by kernel thread.

Hope it answers your query.

UPDATE: Will calling `printk` in interrupt handler cause a deadlock? No. For example [this extract from makelinux](http://www.makelinux.net/books/lkd2/ch18lev1sec3)

> One property of printk() quickly taken for granted is its robustness.
>   The printk() function is callable from just about anywhere in the
>   kernel at any time. It can be called from interrupt or process
>   context. It can be called while a lock is held. It can be called
>   simultaneously on multiple processors, yet it does not require the
>   caller to hold a lock.

UPDATE2: [Word of caution](http://kernelnewbies.kernelnewbies.narkive.com/9GTNGn6x/printk-in-interrupt-handlers) thanks to tc2keats.

However, if printk is in ISR, it's unlikely to be production code. Probably debugging. So if there is a lock up it should become apparent to the programmer :)

Comment: For IO the one can use *mmiotracer*. It's much better than even `trace_printk()`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I was asked a question that "can a printk create a deadlock if used in interrupt handler ? If yes then why " . I couldn't answer that question . Can you explain me in that context .? :-)